# Replace string in rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following SQL table:

```
create table dbo.Posts (
  Id int identity not null,
  Content nvarchar (max) not null
  -- other columns
)
```

I have many rows on this table and on Content column I often have:

```
http://stage.mydomain.com/something
```

I need to replace http://stage.mydomain.com by http://blog.mydomain.com on Content column of all rows.

How can I do this?

Comment: RTFM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms186862.aspx    `update foo set field=replace(field, 'old', 'new')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update dbo.Posts
set Content = REPLACE(Content,'stage.mydomain.com','blog.mydomain.com')
```

Should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
    UPDATE dbo.Posts set Content = replace(Content, 'http://stage.mydomain.com', 'http://blog.mydomain.com')
```